# HAProxy - Enable maintenance mode if file exists

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

We're using stunnel and HAProxy for our load balancing needs.

In nginx you can enable a maintenance state, based on the existance of a file on a child server (see [Configure nginx to serve a 503 if a file exists](https://serverfault.com/a/156890/74875)).

**Is it possible to put a server node into 'maintenance mode' based on the existance of a file, when using HAProxy?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

If the health check file is missing. Check the disable-on-404 option.